# Area bounded by$ y^2=x^2(1-x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, area, applications

Find the area bounded by $y^2=x^2(1-x^2)$? 
I think in this way as the graph lies between -1 to 1 the area is  4 times of $\int x \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$ limits from 0 to 1. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: yep, it might help to see it this way: $y^2=x^2(x+1)(x-1)$, which highlights symmetry about the $y$ axis (Since when oneof the factors becomes positive, the other switches), and the symmetry about the $x$ should be more obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the area enclosed by such a [lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli) is:
$$ 4\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta = \color{red}{\frac{4}{3}}.$$